# Can I separate app download stats to see one app vs. another?

Tags: app-store-connect

We have released two apps under our iTunes connect / developer account, and it looks like the day by day reporting includes both apps and I can only see it broken down by app for the previous day. Unless I check stats daily and track it elsewhere, I can't see how each Indiv is doing.

Answer (score 1):

If Apple's recent improvements don't let you break out sales per app, you might want to look at a service like AppViz that has programmed that feature in and assists in synthesizing the data most accountants and developers need to understand their sales patterns and account for sales accounting-wise.

- https://appviz.com